# Delete a object from array upto given date javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Hi i have searched all over the place and cannot able to get this things done

I want to delete outdated(upto yesterday) objects from array

My array looks like this

```
 [{"apdate": "09-12-2020", "booked": "14:30"}, 
  {"apdate": "11-12-2020", "booked": "19:30"}, 
  {"apdate": "10-12-2020", "booked": "19:00"}, 
  {"apdate": "17-12-2020", "booked": "14:30"}, 
  {"apdate": "17-12-2020", "booked": "15:30"}, 
  {"apdate": "17-12-2020", "booked": "19:00", "phone": "9898989898"}, 
  {"apdate": "10-01-2021", "booked": "16:00"}, 
  {"apdate": "29-01-2021", "booked": "18:30"}, 
  {"apdate": "01-02-2021", "booked": "14:00", "name": "Anand", "uuid": "cPA7ND7U2jdw7qY6nHf4kWuxyx53"}, 
  {"apdate": "01-02-2021", "booked": "10:00", "name": "Anand", "uuid": "cPA7ND7U2jdw7qY6nHf4kWuxyx53"}, 
  {"apdate": "01-02-2021", "booked": "03:30", "name": "Anand", "uuid": "cPA7ND7U2jdw7qY6nHf4kWuxyx53"}]
```

Please guide me

Comment: What did you try so far? You can simply iterate over the array and compare the "apdate" field with a date which is the max value you want to keep (yesterday e.g.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I want to delete outdated(up to `yesterday`) objects from the array

**To be honest, you should keep in mind that never mutate your data**

`==>` *Just use it based on your needs.*

You can use [`.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to filter your data based on a `given_date`.

```js
const data = [
  {apdate: "09-12-2020", booked: "14:30"}, 
  {apdate: "11-12-2020", booked: "19:30"}, 
  {apdate: "10-12-2020", booked: "19:00"}, 
  {apdate: "17-12-2020", booked: "14:30"}, 
  {apdate: "17-12-2020", booked: "15:30"}, 
  {apdate: "17-12-2020", booked: "19:00", phone: "9898989898"}, 
  {apdate: "10-01-2021", booked: "16:00"}, 
  {apdate: "29-01-2021", booked: "18:30"}, 
  {apdate: "01-02-2021", booked: "14:00", name: "Anand", uuid: "cPA7ND7U2jdw7qY6nHf4kWuxyx53"}, 
  {apdate: "01-02-2021", booked: "10:00", name: "Anand", uuid: "cPA7ND7U2jdw7qY6nHf4kWuxyx53"}, 
  {apdate: "01-02-2022", booked: "03:30", name: "Anand", uuid: "cPA7ND7U2jdw7qY6nHf4kWuxyx53"}
  ];
  
const convertStringToDate = (strDate) => {
  const values = strDate.split("-");
  return new Date(values[2], values[1] - 1, values[0]);
};

const filterDataByGivenDate = (data, givenDate) =>  data.filter(r => convertStringToDate(r.apdate) >= givenDate);


const today = new Date();
const yesterday = today.setDate(today.getDate() - 1);

console.log(filterDataByGivenDate(data, yesterday));
```

**A more elegant way is using [`moment.js`](https://momentjs.com/)**

```js
const data = [
  {apdate: "09-12-2020", booked: "14:30"}, 
  {apdate: "11-12-2020", booked: "19:30"}, 
  {apdate: "10-12-2020", booked: "19:00"}, 
  {apdate: "17-12-2020", booked: "14:30"}, 
  {apdate: "17-12-2020", booked: "15:30"}, 
  {apdate: "17-12-2020", booked: "19:00", phone: "9898989898"}, 
  {apdate: "10-01-2021", booked: "16:00"}, 
  {apdate: "29-01-2021", booked: "18:30"}, 
  {apdate: "01-02-2021", booked: "14:00", name: "Anand", uuid: "cPA7ND7U2jdw7qY6nHf4kWuxyx53"}, 
  {apdate: "01-02-2021", booked: "10:00", name: "Anand", uuid: "cPA7ND7U2jdw7qY6nHf4kWuxyx53"}, 
  {apdate: "01-02-2022", booked: "03:30", name: "Anand", uuid: "cPA7ND7U2jdw7qY6nHf4kWuxyx53"}
  ];
  
const filterDataByGivenDate = (data, givenDate) => data.filter(r => moment(r.apdate, 'DD-MM-YYYY').isSameOrAfter(givenDate));

const yesterday = moment().subtract(1, 'days');
console.log(filterDataByGivenDate(data, yesterday));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

---

> The `filter()` method *creates a new array* with all elements that pass
> the test implemented by the provided function.

Comment: Can you please teach me how to delete the object via function

Comment: Oh no, you should keep in mind that never mutate your data. Just use it based on your needs.

Comment: It is because it is stored in a firestore document, to keep document size thin i asked for this..

Comment: So you can *update* with the newest `filtered data`, though :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Lodash Filter](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#filter) & combining it will [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) will do the trick.

```js
const data = [
    {"apdate": "09-12-2020", "booked": "14:30"}, 
    {"apdate": "11-12-2020", "booked": "19:30"}, 
    {"apdate": "10-12-2020", "booked": "19:00"}, 
    {"apdate": "17-12-2020", "booked": "14:30"}, 
    {"apdate": "17-12-2020", "booked": "15:30"}, 
    {"apdate": "17-12-2020", "booked": "19:00", "phone": "9898989898"}, 
    {"apdate": "10-01-2021", "booked": "16:00"}, 
    {"apdate": "29-01-2021", "booked": "18:30"}, 
    {"apdate": "01-02-2021", "booked": "14:00", "name": "Anand", "uuid": "cPA7ND7U2jdw7qY6nHf4kWuxyx53"}, 
    {"apdate": "01-02-2021", "booked": "10:00", "name": "Anand", "uuid": "cPA7ND7U2jdw7qY6nHf4kWuxyx53"}, 
    {"apdate": "01-02-2021", "booked": "03:30", "name": "Anand", "uuid": "cPA7ND7U2jdw7qY6nHf4kWuxyx53"}
];

const filteredData = _.filter(data, item => {
    const apdate = moment(item.apdate, 'DD-MM-YYYY');
    const today = moment();
    const difference = apdate.diff(today, 'days');
    
    // You can modify the condition according to your requirements;
    return difference >= 0;
});

console.log(filteredData)
```

Answer (score 1):

Filter the array and keep the only ones you need. Add your date comparision logic as your need.

```js
let a = [{"apdate": "09-12-2020", "booked": "14:30"}, 
  {"apdate": "11-12-2020", "booked": "19:30"}, 
  {"apdate": "10-12-2020", "booked": "19:00"}, 
  {"apdate": "17-12-2020", "booked": "14:30"}, 
  {"apdate": "17-12-2020", "booked": "15:30"}, 
  {"apdate": "17-12-2020", "booked": "19:00", "phone": "9898989898"}, 
  {"apdate": "10-01-2021", "booked": "16:00"}, 
  {"apdate": "29-01-2021", "booked": "18:30"}, 
  {"apdate": "01-02-2021", "booked": "14:00", "name": "Anand", "uuid": "cPA7ND7U2jdw7qY6nHf4kWuxyx53"}, 
  {"apdate": "01-02-2021", "booked": "10:00", "name": "Anand", "uuid": "cPA7ND7U2jdw7qY6nHf4kWuxyx53"}, 
  {"apdate": "01-02-2021", "booked": "03:30", "name": "Anand", "uuid": "cPA7ND7U2jdw7qY6nHf4kWuxyx53"}];
  
a = a.filter(obj => {
  // add your date comparison logic here and return true for elements you want to keep
  // in this example it will keep elements with '01-02-2021'
  // you may add here your logic to compare dates
  return obj.apdate === '01-02-2021';
})

// now this way you have cleared elements from a
console.log(a);
```